# How to get the localized day of an NSDate as string?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an NSDate object and must create a label that indicates the day of the week in a short 3-char style like 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', ... and localized to the short representation in any language.

The date formatter EEE has 3 chars but how does that translate to languages like Chinese which probably only have one character?

Comment: Yes, `NSDateFormatter` it is. You need to `setDateFormat:` of the formatter object. Use this link for unicode date format patterns. http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date%5FFormat%5FPatterns

Comment: the Bible is the **[NSDateFormatter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**, _Managing Weekday Symbols_ section.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. I don't understand the Managing Weekday Symbols section. It lets me set weekday symbols. So what?

Comment: Have you tried turning your device into chinese to check what you got?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE"];
NSString *strDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
[formatter release];
//Commented out the following line as weekday can be of one letter (requirement changed)
//strDate = [strDate substringToIndex:3];   //This way Monday = Mon, Tuesday = Tue
```

Answer (score 4):

To use the correct locale you'll want to set the `dateFormat` on the instance of `NSDateFormatter` using the [`+ dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDateFormatter/dateFormatFromTemplate%3aoptions%3alocale%3a) method.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EEE" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSLog(@"Weekday using %@: %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier], [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);

// Test what Chinese will look like without changing device locale in settings
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"zh_CN"];
NSLog(@"Weekday using zh_CN: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

This prints:

> Weekday using en_US: Thu
>   Weekday using zh_CN: 周四

Answer (score 1):

This will print what you need:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *day = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
[formatter release];
if ([day length] > 3) day = [day substringToIndex:3];
NSLog(@"%@", day);
```

Comment: @ProudMember updated my answer. If day string is longer then 3 chars then it is cropped. GL

Comment: Folks please stop fighting. My question still is not entirely answered. I asked about the localization aspect and got no answer.